# open My app using URL not working Android

Tags: android, intentfilter

I am trying to open my app when click on this link `www.example.com/someresource/117` in facebook

so I am using this Intent filter

```
<intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <data
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="www.example.com/"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
```

but for some reason the app doesn't open on clicking the link.

is there any thing that I am missing in my intent filter ?

Edit :

after some testing with the previous intent filter I found that when I share the link on whatsApp and then click on it the app opens successfully but it doesn't work if I am sharing the link on facebook only, when I click on the link in facebook, facebook just opens the link in a web view inside the facebook app.

Is there a problem in the new facebook sdk or app ?

How can I avoid opening the link in this webview ?

Answer (score 0):

you can give the schema like this.

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="myappName" android:host="www.example.com" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
</intent-filter>
```

and url should be

```
<a href="myappName://www.example.com">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, after some testing I found that when I share the link on whatsApp and then click on it the app opens successfully but it doesn't work if I am sharing the link on facebook only, when I click on the link in facebook, facebook just opens the link in a web view inside the facebook app. Is there a problem in the new facebook sdk or app ? How can I avoid openning the in this webview ?

Comment: check my edited answer. In that you should replace the 'http' schema with something I mentioned. This will stop the browser from opening